# Верно ли сочетаются слова?

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли такое предложение: "По набережной прогуливалась пара - это были мужчина и женщина средних лет". Верно ли это сочетание "парА" с "былИ" ведь пара - единственное число, а тут "былИ". Но и "былА" вроде не употребишь. Помогите, пожалуйста. И правильно ли я поставила тире?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение возможно, но естественнее оно будет звучать без "это были". Заодно и ваш вопрос уйдет. )))

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза довольно странная с точки зрения смысла, так как тут подчеркивается возраст женщины, но не говорится о возрасте мужчины, хотя судя по использованию слова "мужчина", а не "молодой человек" или "старик" они с женщиной примерно одного возраста. Если это так, то фразу вполне можно сократить до "По набережной прогуливалась пара среднего возраста". Одно из значений слова "пара" - это как раз встречающиеся мужчина и женщина.

Если оставлять фразу в неизменном виде, то конечно "были", так как подлежащее "мужчина и женщина".

Тире в предложении возможно как авторский знак, но я бы ограничился запятой, ничего, что следовало бы подчеркивать длительной паузой (тире), я здесь не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. В предложении говорится о возрасте и мужчины и женщины. Они оба средних лет. Возможно, у меня вышло несколько коряво и неудачно в плане написания. Я посчитала "Мужчина средних лет и женщина средних лет" = "мужчина и женщина средних лет".

Answer (score 1):

"По набережной прогуливалась пара - это были мужчина и женщина средних лет".

Знаки препинания поставлены верно. Это БСП, тире ставится при наличии указательного местоимения, согласование во мн. числе делается во втором предложении (а "пара" в первом предложении).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!